# Which side is this distribution skewed towards to?

Tags: statistics

I'm having some difficulties identifying the skew of the distribution for the qqplot below.

[image]
Can anyone enlighten me on what skew this is?

Answer (score 1):

You see in the right tail the sample quantiles are further out than a normal would be and in the left tail they're further in. This means a fat right tail and a thin left tail.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thank you!